# How to get the exact message Label from a Gmail thread in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

There's a method `getLabels()` but it works for threads only.
However if you switch off Threads in Gmail settings, you can set labels to messages separately.

How can I get a message label in Google Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Scripts cannot work with labels on the message level. See the relevant [Apps Script issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5251).

The labeling process in Gmail is plagued by the issue of threading. This affects even people not using Apps Script, see [How do I work around labels being applied to individual messages and not conversations in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74238)

Comment: That's it :(. Thanks for the reply!